# Cisco ASA adding ISP static IP

Tags: firewall, cisco, isp

We're about to switch from our old ISP to a new one. How do I assign static ISP-assigned IP CISCO ASA interface? Should I define it under NAT or Access Rules? Is it easier through console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the interface IP under interfaces.

(Configuration->Device Setup->Interfaces)

ASDM vs Console is a matter of preference. I stopped using the console after ASDM 6.x got launched, as you can do everything there.

Comment: Found it! Thanks! Could I still keep my old ISP ip just as a backup? I am assigning the new one for outside network.

Comment: Yes, you could - but then you'll need to use another interface or create VLAN's (wich requires a managed L2 switch at a minimum)

Answer (score 1):

In the ASDM, it's under "Interfaces".

On the command line:

```
interface g0/X
 ip address 192.0.2.45 255.255.255.0
```

And you'd probably also want a route for your new ISP, depending on exactly how you're coordinating the cut-over..

```
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.0.2.1 1
```

Comment: Is route outside for setting up the gateway?

Comment: @servercooler Yes indeed.

Comment: Can I assign more than one ip?